# Ada: Index in for loop over an array range has unexpected value

Tags: matrix, ada

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I would like to iterate over every element in a matrix and display:

- The Element Value
- The Element Index (I, J)

The code below gives me the following output:

```
(-2147483648, -2147483648) =  1.00000E+00
(-2147483648, -2147483647) =  2.00000E+00
(-2147483648, -2147483646) =  3.00000E+00
(-2147483647, -2147483648) =  4.00000E+00
(-2147483647, -2147483647) =  5.00000E+00
(-2147483647, -2147483646) =  6.00000E+00
```

I would expect to see 1 instead of -2147483648 and 2 instead of -2147483647.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
with Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays; use Ada.Numerics.Real_Arrays;
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Index is
   Matrix : Real_Matrix := (( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ),
                            ( 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 ));
begin
   for I in Matrix'Range(1) loop
      for J in Matrix'Range(2) loop
         Put_Line("(" & Integer'Image(I) & ", " &
                   Integer'Image(J) & ") = " &
                   Float'Image(Matrix(I, J)));
      end loop;
   end loop;
end Index;
```

Comment: Apparently the Real_Matrix type uses `Integer` as its index type - and the default value if not otherwise specified is `Integer'First`. In Ada you are encouraged to declare and use your own types appropriate to your problem, so declare an array type (along the lines of Real_Matrix) with Natural (starts at 0) or Positive (you get it) or a ranged subtype, and use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index type of `Real_Matrix` is `Integer`, which starts at `-2147483648` on your platform, which explains the numbers you are seeing. However, since the type is unconstrained, you can specify your own index in an array aggregate:

```
Matrix : Real_Matrix := ( 1 => ( 1 => 1.0, 2 => 2.0, 3 => 3.0 ),
                          2 => ( 1 => 4.0, 2 => 5.0, 3 => 6.0 ));
```

Comment: Thanks egilhh and Brian for the quick responses!